# PunchThrough LightBlue how do you make a virtual device send a notification?

Tags: ios, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-peripheral

I'm developing an Android app that is a BLE central. I don't yet have access to the peripheral device. This would be a typical scenario for a virtual device simulator like LightBlue. I can scan and connect client-peri and I can enable notifications by writing the CCCD. If I use LightBlue's Time profile I can get Current Time characteristic notifications once per second. What I need to do is to add a custom characteristic and make that send notifications either at a specified interval or preferrably when pressing a button. How do I do that?
I'm also all ears for other methods or apps that can help me. I can't program my own peripheral app because I only have an iPhone and I don't have access to a development environment for iOS at the moment.
Hoping for insights!
thanks!

Comment: Do you have something running a recent version of Linux? Maybe a Raspberry Pi? You could use it to represent your peripheral. Example at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server

Comment: @ukBaz - very true, but unfortunately I'm stuck with limited resources while travelling. My hope is that Punsch Through or somebody else would have taken the final step to completion of an otherwise excellent tool but I can't find any information online.